# Blank window when launching Chrome Packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-app

When I launch my Chrome Packaged app It sounds but doesn't loads, I only get a blank (empty) window. I have checked already the console to be sure that there are not javascript errors.

I'm using this function on my background.js script

```
    chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
     chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
     'width': 1024,
     'height': 768,
     });
    });
```

It's very strange because the sound of my app starts but the window remains empty. My application is made using Sencha Animator.

Comment: Following another answer suggestions I realized that the problem is not on my index.html but when I call this external CSS https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1306790/style.css Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just tried using your CSS here and it does work. Maybe there is a CSS rule that is throwing an error in GPU when applied to an element. You can either share your html here or try to remove element by element until you find the offending one. You can also fill a bug in http://crbug.com/new with a simpler but complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your index.html must be causing an error.

1. Try one of the [chrome-app-samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples).
2. Try editing your index.html to be trivial, and then slowly adding back your content until you find the error.
3. Check that you are viewing the errors in both the background page and the launched page. You can right click the app window and inspect element to see it's inspector. You can use chrome://extensions to see the inspector view for all your pages.

Comment: I follow your suggestion. I made some test and finally I saw that my app crashes when I call an external css. I cant put my CSS code here because it is too long but you can download it here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1306790/style.css

Comment: You can't use external CSS. The CSS needs to be packaged with the app. In order to use external CSS, you would have to fetch it by XHR, save to the filesystem, then pull it back into a buffer and use a `data:` url for it.

The CSP directive preventing loading an external CSS is:

    style-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource: 'unsafe-inline';

You can read more about the CSP for packaged apps at http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_csp.html

Answer (score 0):

Even though it does not answer this question I just want to let you know that I finally tried Node-Webkit https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit to achieve mi goal: having a desktop packaged version of my HTML5 app.

It works so good.